# How do I parse '<%= =>' in grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, parsing, gruntjs

A lot of grunt plugins allow for this syntax when telling it to include files:

```
['<%= src_dir %>/common/**/*.js', '<%= src_dir %>/app/**/*.js']
```

or

```
['<%= test_files.js %>']
```

Is there any way I can call into some library that will parse these and give me an array of the actual output? Or is this built directly into grunt? I am not sure what terms to google to even make this show up.

Thanks

Comment: I believe putting code within `<% %>` will cause it to be rendered. Does this work? Is this what you mean?

Comment: Essentially, what I'd like to do, is create some code that operates on these strings and do the parsing myself. I did some more research, and I think it's related to grunt.template.process perhaps. Looks like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either looking for [**`grunt.config.get`**](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.get), [**`grunt.config.process`**](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.process) or [**`grunt.template.process`**](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template#grunt.template.process), depending on where you are getting the values from and how you want to process them.

> **grunt.config.get**
>
> Get a value from the project's Grunt configuration. If `prop` is specified, that property's value is returned, or `null` if that property is not defined. If `prop` isn't specified, a copy of the entire config object is returned. Templates strings will be recursively processed using the `grunt.config.process` method.
>
> ```
> grunt.config.get([prop])
> ```

---

> **grunt.config.process**
>
> Process a value, recursively expanding `<% %>` templates (via the `grunt.template.process` method) in the context of the Grunt config, as they are encountered. this method is called automatically by `grunt.config.get` but not by `grunt.config.getRaw`.
>
> ```
> grunt.config.process(value)
> ```
>
> [...]

---

> **grunt.template.process**
>
> Process a Lo-Dash template string. The `template` argument will be processed recursively until there are no more templates to process.
>
> The default data object is the entire config object, but if `options.data` is set, that object will be used instead. The default template delimiters are `<% %>` but if `options.delimiters` is set to a custom delimiter name (set with `grunt.template.addDelimiters`), those template delimiters will be used instead.
>
> ```
> grunt.template.process(template [, options])
> ```
>
> Inside templates, the grunt object is exposed so that you can do things like `<%= grunt.template.today('yyyy') %>`. *Note that if the data object already has a `grunt` property, the grunt API will not be accessible in templates.*
>
> In this example, the `baz` property is processed recursively until there are no more `<% %>` templates to process.
>
> ```
> var obj = {
>   foo: 'c',
>   bar: 'b<%= foo %>d',
>   baz: 'a<%= bar %>e'
> };
> grunt.template.process('<%= baz %>', {data: obj}) // 'abcde'
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I think grunt.config.process is what I was looking for!